# Python crash, glibc detected /zope/z_if_algerie/Python-2.6/bin/python: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer

Tags: python, linux, plone, glibc, zope

I run Plone 4.1.3 on a linux 3.2.13-xxxx-std-ipv6-64 with python 2.6.

Plone is in ZEO, with pound and apache.

After browsing my website, I've got an error (in the terminal) :

```
*** glibc detected *** /zope/z_if_algerie/Python-2.6/bin/python: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000040e70b0 ***
```

And all zeoclients are stoped.

[Here is the link to the full traceback](http://pastealacon.com/31018).

Someone know what's going on ?

Thank you !

Comment: Something `lxml` related; no idea what though.

Comment: If it's lxml-related, then the big variables are whether or not you're using system or installer-built python and libxml2/libxstl.

Comment: I use installer-built python.
I use unified installer

Comment: @Jihaisse This is a total guess, but there was a bug in `lxml` for versions lower than `2.3.5`. So if back in 2012 you were (likely) using a version lower than 2.3.5, you would have hit this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxml/+bug/984936